# Return duplicate with the highest adjuacent value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to manipulate Excel data given the following values:

[image: img]

In the `Result` column, I want to identify the duplicate values, in this case, `Apple`, and get the Apple with the **larger `Weight` value**.

I was wondering what could the Excel formula be? I tried with the `COUNTIF()` function, but I don't know the continuation of the formula.

Comment: What would the "result" cells be in this example?  I'm thinking it would be 51, 34, 51, but I'm not entirely sure that is correct.

Comment: @M.Wise Wise, I guess he expects the same result 51,34,51. Even if he doesn't, I would like to know how to get that result with the formula?

Comment: @Dhamo, assuming the grid is in cells B2:D5, I would type this formula in cell D3:  =MAX(IF($B$3:$B$5=$B3,$C$3:$C$5)).  This is an array formula which needs to be executed by pressing CTRL + Shift + Enter.  Dragging it down to Cell D5 would get the desired result.

Comment: @M.Wise, Awesome, Thank you!

Comment: I interpret the question as needing to have only **one** value returned (Apples/51), and presumably nothing returned if there are no duplicates. ...but this is the kind of thing that would be handy to clarify if the OP hung around after asking a question, instead of leaving others to speculate.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for replying late. Yes. The expected values in “Result” column should be 51, 34, 51.

Comment: @Dhamo and urthkey, not sure if you guys noticed, but I posted an answer that I believe is a simpler way (no need for array formula). You may want to have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

**`VLOOKUP`** can do the job :)

You just need to sort `Weight` "Largest to Smallest" as `VLOOKUP` finds the first match from the top:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;$A$2:$B$4;2;FALSE)
```

The duplicates you can identify with Conditional formatting.